# Symfony - mocking token storage interface and return user object

Tags: php, unit-testing, symfony, testing

In my service method I am mocking I have part where I am persisting entity from user table like:

```
$user = $this->tokenStorage->getToken()->getUser();
$userFirstName = 'Unknown user';

$new = new MyEntity();
if ($user != 'anon.') {
    $new->setUserId($user);
    $userFirstName = $user->getFirstName();
 }
```

I am writing that part in a separate test method where I want to return sepcific User object, meaning I want to test it..

```
public function testUser()
{
    $tokenStorage = $this->createMock(TokenStorageInterface::class);
    $userRepo = $this->createMock(UserRepository::class);

    $username = ['username' => 'test@test.com']; // this will find the entry in the DB

    $testUserObject = new User();

    $userRepo->expects($this->any())
    ->method('findOneBY')
    ->with($username)
    ->will($this->returnValue($testUserObject));

    $user = $tokenStorage->getToken()->getUser();
    $this->assertEquals($testUserObject, $user);
}
```

but I get:

> Error: Call to a member function getUser() on null

and I think this is the user in my test db..

Or maybe this is not a proper way to test this case? Can someone help I am new at writing tests..

Another question is, can I use returned value of this test method and use it's user object for testing whole method where I persist this user object?

Answer (score 0):

Regard the error, you're not saying what `$tokenStorage->getToken()` will return. As you're mocking the token storage, a `getToken` invocation you've not stubbed, ends up to return a `null` value.

Said that, you should really [don't mock what you don't own](https://8thlight.com/blog/eric-smith/2011/10/27/thats-not-yours.html) (basically, don't mock third party code) as you can't control it. This kind of test should be improved in two ways

1. Don't test it at unit level but at integration/functional/e2e level.
2. Write you're own abstraction for token storage (can be useless if this is an application service rather than a domain service).

Of course no one prevents you to mock what you don't own, that's just an advice.

Regard this sentece

> can I use returned value of this test method and use it's user object for testing whole method where I persist this user object

if I understand correctly, you're trying to test a private method here? If so, just don't do that and test only the public API (public methods) of your class. Instead, if this is a public method, is perfectly OK to test it even if it's used by another public method.